# Metric on the unit circle

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $d$ be a metric on the unit circle $S^1$ which defines the usual topology. Let $D = \sup_{x, y \in S^1} d(x,y)$ be the diameter for $S^1$ under this metric.

Is it true that the map $d : S^1 \times S^1 \to [0,D]$ is an open map?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is not always open. Here is a simple counter-example.

The unit circle is homeomorphic to the following figure.

[image]

This figure is endowed with the euclidean metric of the plane, that we then transport to a metric on the unit circle using the homeomorphism.

Now consider the two points in red on the figure (or more exactly, their image on the unit circle by the homeomorphism). Let us call them $x$ and $y$. The distance will send any small neighborhood of $(x,y)$ to a set of the form $(\delta, \delta']$, with $\delta' < D$.

Consequently, this map is not open.

Comment: The link does not work.

Comment: Very strange, it works for me. I just used the feature provided by stackexchange to upload a picture.

Comment: Here is an other link, using an external website: https://ibb.co/bEg8tz

Comment: The map is not open in any topology, yes, even when two topologies are homeomorphic. But considering the shape of the unit circle in the euclidean plane, the same argument does not apply. If your question was about the unit circle up to homeomorphism, then the function is not open in every topology homeomorphic to the usual one as you have correctly shown. On the usual "circumference with radius 1" the function is indeed open.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. My question was about a metric on the unit circle which defines the usual topology. This includes the metric I mention in my answer. The two topologies are not merely homeomorphic, they are the same.

Comment: I see. I must have interpreted the object in question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. A basis for the product $S_1\times S_1$ is given by the product of open sets $U_1\times U_2$, where $U_i$ is an open ball in $S_1$.
The function maps pairs of such open sets to the set:
$$d(U_1, U_2) = \{x\in \Bbb{R} | \inf_{(x_1, x_2)\in (U_1, U_2)} d(x_1, x_2) < x < \sup_{(x_1, x_2)\in (U_1, U_2)} d(x_1, x_2)\} $$
And you can see that the only such sets where the image is a closed interval (or half-closed) are those that partially overlap or such that they include points that are opposite to each other. In those cases, the image includes the points $0$ or $D$. Intervals that include those points are open in $[0, D]$ in the subspace topology.

Since the function maps basis sets to open sets, it is an open map.

Comment: Can you please add more details, when you say that when the image is half closed, then it must includes 0 or $D$?

Comment: If you do not change the shape of the circle, it is an evident property. If you do change it, then you're changing the topology and thus working with a different set of distances between points.

Comment: You seem to make a confusion between a topological space and a metric space. The two different metrics give a different "shape" to the circle, whatever you might mean by "shape", but they are the same topological spaces, with the same families of open sets.